CSS make rows same height with FlexBox
I'm trying to build a complex 'table' style layout with Div and FlexBox. The page is using Bootstrap 5.2.x for the main layout.
Check out my test page
I am trying to make the 'rows' the same height across. So the middle single row will stretch to the full height of the 'table' to the left.
I've tried a number of different variations of layouts and CSS but no success! :-(
Can anyone offer any advice or examples? This is the visual:

My table code is shown below.
<div id="shrpa-table-container" class="link-id-45594 cat-id-10223 tlcat-id-10223">
<h3>Aircraft information</h3>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-5 shrpa-table">
        <div class="shrpa-table-title"><h4>Aircraft size and type</h4></div>
        <div class="shrpa-table-rows">
            <div class="shrpa-table-row shrpa-table-pad">
                <span class="shrpa-table-caption">TurboProp</span><span class="shrpa-table-value"></span>               </div>
            <div class="shrpa-table-row-alt shrpa-table-pad">
                <span class="shrpa-table-caption">Light Jet</span><span class="shrpa-table-value">Cessna Citation CJ2+, Cessna Citation CJ3+</span>             </div>
            <div class="shrpa-table-row shrpa-table-pad">
                <span class="shrpa-table-caption">Mid Jet</span><span class="shrpa-table-value">Embraer Legacy 450, Embraer Praetor 500</span>              </div>
            <div class="shrpa-table-row-alt shrpa-table-pad">
                <span class="shrpa-table-caption">Super Mid</span><span class="shrpa-table-value"></span>               </div>
            <div class="shrpa-table-row shrpa-table-pad">
                <span class="shrpa-table-caption">Heavy Jet</span><span class="shrpa-table-value"></span>               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 shrpa-table">
    <div class="shrpa-table-title"><h4>Aircraft age</h4></div>
    <div class="shrpa-table-rows">
        <div class="shrpa-table-row shrpa-table-pad">
            <span class="shrpa-table-value">3 years</span>          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-5 shrpa-table">
    <div class="shrpa-table-title"><h4>Aircraft independent ratings</h4></div>
    <div class="shrpa-table-rows">
        <div class="shrpa-table-row shrpa-table-pad">
            <span class="shrpa-table-caption">Argus rating</span><span class="shrpa-table-value">Platinum Rating</span>         </div>
        <div class="shrpa-table-row-alt shrpa-table-pad">
            <span class="shrpa-table-caption">Wyvern rating</span><span class="shrpa-table-value">Wingman Pro</span>            </div>
        <div class="shrpa-table-row shrpa-table-pad">
            <span class="shrpa-table-caption">ISBAO</span><span class="shrpa-table-value"></span>           </div>
        <div class="shrpa-table-row-alt shrpa-table-pad">
            <span class="shrpa-table-caption">Other rating</span><span class="shrpa-table-value"></span>            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question; please do not (just) send us to external sites.

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

This is a job for Grid layout.

Ralph.m Thanks for the reply, do you have any example code I could follow?

@user1794875 You should only include relevant code in your post. Please either remove the non-bootstrap classes or include their CSS if relevant.

Also, are you only trying to stretch the middle single row to follow the height of the left container, or stretching all shrpa-table-rows to making the columns adds up to the same height? These are two pretty different requirement. Either way you can consider using flex with flex-direction:column or grid.

SyndRain, I have updated the original post with an image of the visual I'm am trying to follow. Apologies I do not understand your first coomet re removing bootstrap classes?
